What is an 'exported' header or an 'exported' include path? What does 'exported' mean in this context?
I have recently started robotics and have been reading the tutorials on ros wiki when I came across this


These lines are used for the case where this ros-package (A) wants to allow itself to be used by another ros-package (B). So "exported" refers to the resources-from-A that must be available to B when B is built.
If you use catkin_create_pkg to create a skeleton pkg, in my opinion the comments within CMakeLists.txt explain it more clearly.
